# How to kill text when overwriting in delete-selection-mode

Tags: emacs

I would like to change the default behaviour of delete-selection-mode so that overwritten selections get killed rather than deleted.  This is the case with a fresh Emacs 24.2:

```
Emacs -Q
(delete-selection-mode)
```

Looking through delsel.el I got close to the behaviour I want:

```
(put 'self-insert-command 'delete-selection 'kill)
```

but this doesn't actually insert the key I type to overwrite the selected text. And it doesn't cater for `'org-self-insert-command` (as an example of unforeseen consequences).

Am I missing something basic?

Comment: Seems like a bug.  You should file a bug report.

Comment: bug report sent, thanks.